# three.js not rendering correctly on iPad Air 2

Tags: javascript, ipad, three.js

I've just started using an iPad Air 2 for work and wanted to start working with equirectangular panoramas. These work great on the desktop, but an iPad/iPhone add some cool options to start using device orientation as the controls.

When I pulled up my script on the iPad, it looks extremely poorly rendered. I can tell what things are, but only because I'm familiar with this photo. I'm really not sure what's causing this issue. As far as I can tell, this looks to be local to the iPad. I've tested that WebGL is available, and that's always passed with flying colors.

In my code, I'm trying to create a sphere and used the photo as the mesh. Like I said, it works on the desktop, just not the iPad. I've been looking around but haven't been able to find any real solutions or very comparable issues being reported. I'm completely stuck on this one.

Here's the sample link: http://www.freeptools.com/mapster/360/2/

Comment: I just verified the crappy rendering on the ipad air 2 both in safari and chrome. Since it is working on the desktop (chrome, firefox) it would have to do with the implementation of webgl on the ipad. Not much you can do unless you open a bug report.

Comment: I wanted to update, I was able to get things working by simply resizing the image. The image was 3584x1792. Not sure why that seemed to be an issue, but resizing the images down to 2048x1024 seemed to do the trick. I'm assuming it was too much image to want to process cleanly as the 2x1 perspective was still there.

Answer (score 2):

You need to resize your image to be a power-of-two. For example, 2048 x 1024.

I would suggest updating to the current version of three.js, and make sure your handle device pixel ratio correctly.

```
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
```

For a panorama example, see this three.js demo: http://threejs.org/examples/misc_controls_deviceorientation.html.

three.js r.70